# Create cohort dropout rate table from raw data

Tags: r

I need help creating a cohort dropout table from raw data.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
DT<-data.table(
id =c (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
     11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
     21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35),
year =c (2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,
       2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,
   2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016),
cohort =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,
        1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3))
```

I want to calculate the dropout rate by cohort, and get a table like this:

```
cohortdt<-data.table(
cohort =c(1,2,3),
drop_rateY1 =c(.60,0.0,0.0),
droprate_Y2 =c (.50,.33,0.0))
```

For cohort 1, the dropout rate at the end of Y1 is 60%. (i.e. 60 percent of students who were originally enrolled dropped out at the end of year 1. The value in Y2 means that 50% of those who remained at the end of year 1, dropped out at the end of year 2.

How can create a table like this from the raw data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

DT %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  count(cohort) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(year, n) %>% 
  mutate(year_1_drop_rate = 1 - (`2015` / `2014`),
         year_2_drop_rate = 1 - (`2016` / `2015`)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(year_1_drop_rate = 0.0,
                  year_2_drop_rate = 0.0)) %>% 
  select(cohort, year_1_drop_rate, year_2_drop_rate)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  cohort year_1_drop_rate year_2_drop_rate
   <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1      1              0.6        0.5000000
2      2              0.0        0.3333333
3      3              0.0        0.0000000
```

1. `group` by year
2. `count` cohort by year groups
3. `ungroup`
4. `spread` year in columns 2014, 2015, and 2016
5. `mutate` twice to get dropout rates for year 1 and year 2
6. `replace_na` to 0
7. `select` cohort, year_1_drop_rate, and year_2_drop_rate

This solution takes a *tidy* dataset and makes it *untidy* by spreading the year variable (i.e. 2014, 2015, and 2016 are separate columns).

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple data.table solution :

```
x <- DT[,.N, by = .(cohort,year)]
```

count the number of student each year on each cohort and create the new data.table x

```
x[,drop := (1-N/(c(NA,N[-.N])))*100,by = cohort]
```

here I make the ratio between the number of student and the number of student the year after (c(NA,N[-.N]) is the shifted vector of N), that gives you the percentage of lost student each year

```
x[,.SD,by = cohort]
   cohort year  N     drop
1:      1 2014 10       NA
2:      1 2015  4 60.00000
3:      1 2016  2 50.00000
4:      2 2015  6       NA
5:      2 2016  4 33.33333
6:      3 2016  9       NA
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No. it's actually showing the number of students who are still enrolled each year.

Comment: So modify your original question, it looks like you explicitly said the opposite : "60 percent of students who were originally enrolled dropped out at the end of year 1". If you want the percentage still enrolled, it is just 100 - the dropout.

Comment: My question is correct. Your solution is incorrect. Your solution calculates a 40% dropout rate for cohort 1 in year 2015.  It should show 60%, like in  tyluRp's  solution.

Comment: @Chris Sorry you are right. I edited my solution following my previous comment. My solution work, is not restricted to the number of year, and needs two lines. Hope you like it